# Running git add in a post-commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add a file to my last commit that contains the hash of my last commit and then amend the current commit with that file. I'm trying to do that in a post-commit hook

I'm using a dummy file that's created in a pre-commit hook, and is removed before the amending commit so as to avoid loops.

The code seems to work fine, except the file isn't staged so the amending commit effectively does nothing. The file is modified and ready to be staged for the next commit, however.

So my question is, can you use git add in a post-commit hooks? A simple search seems to say yes, but it is refusing to work for me.

I use Visual Studio Code.

```
#post-commit hook
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nameDummy=/commitDummy

folderFile=/folder/
nameFile=file.txt

if test -f "$(pwd)${nameDummy}"; then

    rm $(pwd)${nameDummy}
    git add $(pwd)${folderFile}${nameFile} 
    git commit --amend -C HEAD --no-verify

fi  

exit 0
```

Comment: maybe this is XY problem? do you want to also commit the commit's hash into the commit itself?

Comment: if you need the last commit's hash, you can use `git rev-parse HEAD` or view/copy content of `.git/refs/heads/master`

Comment: No. Really the problem is that git add isn't working in my post-commit hook. Everything else works fine. The hash is used for basically non-Git bookkeeping, it's just more convenient than an arbitrary value.

Comment: if you amend the commit, wouldn't the commit hash would be changed? what is the purpose of saving old and unrefered (amended) commit hash?

Comment: also, you can try to `echo $(pwd)${folderFile}${nameFile}` or `echo $(pwd)${folderFile}${nameFile} > /tmp/mydump` and see if the file specified exist or not and debug from there

Comment: I'm trying to automatically add a file containing hash of commit n-1 to current commit n. However git add is not working in the post-commit script. Getting the hash is not the problem, and it isn't the question.

Comment: What is the value of a file mentioning a hash of a commit that will eventually be garbage-collected and vanish into non-existence?

Comment: To precisely know from which commit a branch was created, for example? I've had trouble with devs merging wrong branches and noticing way later. This would let me see which branch are created after these 'bad' merges. It's not retroactive, sure, but it's a start.

Comment: You can't store the current commit's hash ID (because `--amend` kicks the current commit to the curb and installs a new commit with a different hash ID in its place), but you *can* store the current *branch name*. The problem with doing that is that it ultimately has negative value, i.e., it's detrimental to your future (fortunately this is very minor since you can just ignore it once that occurs).

Comment: Again I'm not storing the current commit's hash id. I'm storing the hash of the preceding commit. If I'm currently doing my second commit on a branch, I'm storing the hash of the first commit. If I'm doing the first commit, I'm storing the hash of the commit which is the branch's starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A simple git commit --amend --no-verify --no-edit works wonder.